# Put a div next another div

Tags: html, css

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjacu/t9r9S/4/

It's this

```
<div class="gamedes">
    <img class="miniaturas"src="http://thumbs.mochiads.com/c/g/coaster-racer-3/_thumb_200x200.png">
        <a class="gamede" src="google.es">Hola</a>
        <div class="description">Description about 120 caracters</div><br><br><br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="gamedes">
    <img class="miniaturas"src="http://thumbs.mochiads.com/c/g/coaster-racer-3/_thumb_200x200.png">
        <a class="gamede" src="google.es">Hola</a>
        <div class="description">Description about 120 caracters</div><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
```

And I Want to put the second image, title and text next to the first, like in two columns.

I don't understand why I can't do that because I try all the methods I know and it doesn't work.

Any solution?

Comment: Do you want the whole object next to the image i.e. do you want the box with name and description all to align next to each other?

Comment: Use `float: left` and change `.gamede {}` to `.gamedes {}`: http://jsfiddle.net/t9r9S/6/ (And give it a width.)

Comment: you are missing s in .gamede

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9r9S/7/)

```
.gamedes{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, I have modified a bit on your `html`

Comment: Ok it works perfectly this is the best answer in all the answers thanks!

Comment: What I can modify in my html?

Comment: @Ninjacu I put this text: Hola inside `description` div.

Comment: How did you do this? I'm really interested

Comment: Ok I undertand all now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried floating the divs?

```
.gamedes {
  float:left
}
```

Comment: Thanks but with a inline-block it works better because with a float: left it puts up a title. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First give them specific width and the float them left like this.

```
.gamedes{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: And correct the typo miniaturas"src, separate the src.

Comment: @va5ja - Not having a space between attributes is messy but not related to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.miniaturas {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.description {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 10%;
}

.gamede{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.gamedes {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="gamedes">
    <img class="miniaturas"src="http://thumbs.mochiads.com/c/g/coaster-racer-3/_thumb_200x200.png"><br />
        <a href="#" class="gamedes" src="google.es">Hola</a><br />
  <div class="description">Description about 120 caracters</div>
</div>
<div class="gamedes">
    <img class="miniaturas"src="http://thumbs.mochiads.com/c/g/coaster-racer-3/_thumb_200x200.png"><br />
        <a href="#" class="gamedes" src="google.es">Hola</a><br />
  <div class="description">Description about 120 caracters</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gamedes{
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
.miniaturas {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.description {
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #A4A4A4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Results here: http://jsfiddle.net/2kXFH/